# font-size in vw entity - adjustable scope?

Tags: css, font-size, viewport-units

so I started wondering if there is a way to adjust scope of letter's size using vw?
Lets say we would have:

```
<h1>This is our header</h1>
```

```
h1{ font-size:2vw; }
```

On desktop font would be huge - while on mobile screens would be tiny. So what's the point using vw if you still need to readjust it in media queries?!

Example:
http://css-tricks.com/examples/ViewportTypography/

Comment: you better use at this time usual units as pt,px,em to set your font-size and set max-min or most suitable font-size via mediaqueries. vw and vh units are fun : here an example of what you talk about :) http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/full/qunsm

Comment: Sorry but that doesn't make sense.. Mixing vw with px? Why not em, rem?:P

Comment: vw is coherent with pixel 1vw of 1000 pixels with is 10px , em will be defaut setting of your browser . just tune your mediaqueries to match width and vw/px ratio :)

Comment: 1vw is 1% of screen width, 1 vh is 1% of screen height , font-size takes % from defaut font-size set in your browser, px is left to be use in front of vw and vh if you want a match at some points . By the way , example is not the solution, but shows what you run into playing with vw font-size :)

Answer (score 0):

You got the point that setting `font size` in `vw` units makes it really tiny and unreadable at small viewport. What looks nice on computer screen looks bad on mobile.

**But... why not to use something like "font minimum size" for mobile devices?**

There is **no** such a property as `font-min-size` in CSS but there is a CSS workaround to this problem using `calc()` function.

Consider this:

```
font-size:calc(10px + 0.5vw)
```

You set a default font size for a body using calc function with mixed units - pixels and vw. Have you heard of limits in math? It works the same way.

For a typical screen size of a computer 1366 x 768px, `font-size` would have a value of `16.83px`. When you decrease the viewport to the size of mobile devices for example width `600px` `font-size` would be `13px`. As the viewport gets smaller the `vw` unit is smaller too. Setting `calc(10px + 0.5vw)` therefore we set the minimum font size at `10px`.

For bigger screen like 4K we avoid a situation that the text is too small to see. For 4K screen you have a `font-size` value `29.2px`.

---

**Check out this demo** and try to change your viewport to see changes. The hardest part is to set the best ration `px` and `vw` to get the best user experience.

```css
div{margin:10px 0;font-weight:bold}

#A1{font-size:calc(10px + .6vw)}
#A2{font-size:10px}
#A3{font-size:2vw}

#B1{font-size:calc(16px + .6vw)}
#B2{font-size:16px}
#B3{font-size:2vw}

#C1{font-size:calc(18px + .6vw)}
#C2{font-size:18px}
#C3{font-size:2vw}
```

```html
<div id="A1">Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
<div id="A2">Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
<div id="A3">Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
--------------------
<div id="B1">"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis</div>
<div id="B2">"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis</div>
<div id="B3">"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis</div>
--------------------
<div id="C1">eos qui ratione voluptatem</div>
<div id="C2">eos qui ratione voluptatem</div>
<div id="C3">eos qui ratione voluptatem</div>
```

---

**This solution leaves one question: why is it not widely used??**

I hope someone finds this usefull or maybe improves my answer.